# Can't access AppStore connect

Tags: ios, macos, app-store-connect

Whenever I try to login to my AppStore connect console, I'm getting redirected to this page(https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/gettingstarted). This looks like to be older iTunes connect page which is no longer operational. I'm not able to access my AppStore connect console at all and have been facing this issue from past 5 to 6 days. Have also tried accessing it from other browsers and in incognito, nothing seems to work. Any idea what would be the reason? Anyone else facing this issue?

Comment: We can only help with specific development related questions. this sounds like you should contact Apple support. We do not know the internals of Itunes connect redirects and URLs

Comment: Tried other browsers or deleting relevant cookies/app data?

Comment: I don't understand the down vote here. 
I'm asking this here because the reach is more and it will help me get any info possible on this issue from any of the developers who have faced a similar issue.
And Yes I have already raised a bug report but haven't yet got any reply from Apple, that's why I'm posting here for help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Comment: @ChengappaCD did you solve your problem?

Comment: @ZakharovRoman Ya we could solve it, have answered below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I contacted the Apple Support for this issue, but they couldn't figure out the issue right away and asked for some time to investigate the issue.

Meanwhile I could get credentials of our accounts `team-agent` and on logging in with his credentials we saw that in the Users and Roles section all the users were removed except the `team-agent`, even the admins(`which was my role`). And this was the reason why I couldn't access the App Store Console. The `team agent` user also confirmed that he has not deleted any of the users.

So, post realising what was the issue, we just added all the team members again in `Users and Roles` section, post that it's working fine. We also informed the apple support regarding what had happened, but they were not able to figure out why the issue occurred and told us to inform them if it ever reproduces again in future.

Hope this helps! :]

Comment: Thank you for the answer